# Join Collection With Country Table

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-1.8, collection, collection-filtering

I have stored country id in my custom table. **How to join the my custom collection with country collection to get a Country Name.**

I have tried below code but its not working :

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('XXX/XXX')->getCollection()->addFieldToSelect(array('city','country_id')); 
$collection->getSelect()->join( 
    array('second'=>$collection->getTable('directory/country')),
    'main_table.country_id = second.code',
    array('second.name') 
)->getData();
```

Hope someone will provide some useful information.

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: I get error : SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'second.name' in 'field list'

Comment: The country table doesn't have a name. The names come afaik from Zend_Directory: `Mage::app()->getLocale()->getCountryTranslation($country_code);`

Comment: yes its correct, using inner join how to get country name?

Comment: There is no way, because the country names are in XML files: `lib/Zend/Locale/Data/de.xml` de is only one of the many XML files which are there.

Answer (score 3):

The country table doesn't have a name.

The names come afaik from Zend_Directory, you can use this code to get the name from the code which is in `second.iso2_code`

```
Mage::app()->getLocale()->getCountryTranslation($country_code);
```

Sadly, there is no way to "join" the information into any sql query, because all the data is saved in files:

```
lib/Zend/Locale/Data/de.xml // de is only one of the many XML files which are there.
```